# JUnit testing throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, junit

I recently came across a [tool for android hotswapping](http://www.instareloader.com/). It has a tutorial to begin using with eclipse(Luna) http://www.instareloader.com/enabling-instareloader-in-the-eclipse-ide/ .

What that tutorial says is:

1. Right Click on the main project, and click on New Test project
2. Add their library jar into the junit test.

This is my main project's xml:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

And this is my TestProject's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.layoutreloadmyown.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
 android:sharedUserId="com.test">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.layoutreloadmyown" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="instareloader.ip"
            android:value="192.168.56.1" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="instareloader.port"
            android:value="18080" />

                 <meta-data 
                    android:name="instareloader.file.logger"
                    android:value="true" /> 


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.layoutreloadmyown.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I did everything that it said, and exactly that, But I get a classnotfoundException:

**08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.layoutreloadmyown.test/com.example.layoutreloadmyown.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.layoutreloadmyown.MainActivity
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.layoutreloadmyown.MainActivity
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
08-16 12:29:51.995: E/AndroidRuntime(1745):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)**

Answer (score 0):

You have not integrated main application in your test project.

Right click test project->Properties -> Java Build Path ->Select Projects. Integrate the project which you are going to do Unit Test.

Comment: but I can see my project in the list

Comment: will you please post the screenshot of the location which I said. @harvey_slash

Comment: it says classNotFoundException which means unit test case which you are hitting the main project can't identify the class name